# Einstein's notation for matrix multiplication $G^{-1} B$

Tags: notation

Let us define $G$ as the metric tensor and $B$ as a tensor compatible with metric tensor $G$. How can we denote $G^{-1} \, B$ in Einstein's notation?

I know $g^{ij}$ is every entry of the inverse metric tensor and lower/upper $B_j^i$ is used on the sum of vector/matrices product, but $g^{ij} \, B_j^i$ does not seem right.

I can denote the inverse metric tensor $G^{-1}$ as ⅁ and the desired result would be ⅁${}_{k}^{i} B_{j}^{k}$. However, it is cheating. :-P

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question without more context. Conventionally the answer would be $g^{i j} B_j{}^k$, but Einstein notation is not meant to be used with arbitrary matrices.

Comment: It should be used everywhere. :-P

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I like Einstein notation and even more Penrose graphical notation. But it is meant for the geometry of inner product spaces, not arbitrary matrices.

Comment: Why is your index $k$ ahead $B$ of some indentation space?

Comment: Because otherwise you can't distinguish between $B_j{}^k$ and $B^k{}_j$...

Comment: Oh, I see. I am myself a novice in Einstein's notation. Could you point out some easy-going article?